# accessing an property inside an object for showtimes

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have created an object class called "Movie" that contains a property called "showtimes" which is of type NSMutableArray.

Now I have another class called "LocalShowtimes" that contains a property called moviesArray  of type NSMutableArray which is filled with objects of type "Movie"

I am know trying know to get to the first object of the moviesArray and get its property "showtimes" in order to do something with it.

This is what I am trying:

`NSMutableArray *theShowtimes =[(Movie *)[[moviesArray] objectAtIndex:[o]] showtimes];`

but the compiler is complaining with "Expected Identifier"

can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use `objectAtIndex:` or the indexer:

```
// Like this - the old syntax
NSMutableArray *theShowtimes =[[moviesArray objectAtIndex:o] showtimes]; 

// Or like this - the new syntax
NSMutableArray *theShowtimes =[moviesArray[o] showtimes];
```

Answer (score 0):

dasblinkenlight has provided the solution to your problem, but just to add an answer to your literal question (*"... what am I doing wrong?"*):

The square brackets in Objective-C denote a message being passed to an object. In its most simple form, it looks like this:

```
[myObject importantMessage]
```

In your code you have this:

```
[[moviesArray] objectAtIndex:[o]]
```

which means that the compiler thinks that you want to send a message to your object `moviesArray`, but you don't actually send any message. The compiler tries to tell you that by using the expression "expected identifier".

The identifier it expects is the name of the message you apparently want to send to the object.

Now, in your case, you don't really want to send any message, since `moviesArray` is a perfectly fine array on its own, but the compiler doesn't know that.

Hence, as dasblinkenlight shows, all you have to do is to remove the superfluous square bracket around the object, so the compiler doesn't think that you are trying to send it a message.

The same logic applies to `[o]`, with the added complication that `o` is not an object - it is (or should be) a simple integer. Integers (and floats, double, etc.) are known as primitive types and should just be handled as normal C variables, because that is what they are.